# How to sort files in a folder using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have these files in a folder:

```
chap11-solutions.pdf
chap12-solutions.pdf
chap13-solutions.pdf
chap14-solutions.pdf
chap15-solutions.pdf
chap16-solutions.pdf
chap17-solutions.pdf
chap21-solutions.pdf
chap22-solutions.pdf
chap23-solutions.pdf
chap24-solutions.pdf
chap25-solutions.pdf
chap26-solutions.pdf
chap2-solutions.pdf
chap3-solutions.pdf
chap4-solutions.pdf
chap5-solutions.pdf
chap6-solutions.pdf
chap7-solutions.pdf
chap8-solutions.pdf
chap9-solutions.pdf
```

how do I sort them in this way: chap1..., chap...2, ...., chap11..., chap12,... using Ubuntu bash shell? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
ls|sort -V
```

The `-V` parameter ensures that `chap10` is considered upper that `chap9`.

Comment: Just be aware that the `-V` option works only for relatively new GNU coreutils - it doesn't work for 5.93 (the one that's shipped by default with Mac OS 10.6).

Comment: OP uses Ubuntu, so he likely have a recent GNU coreutils :)

Answer (score 9):

GNU `ls` has a version sort built-in:

```
ls -lv
```

Comment: thanks for this new very useful info, I never know this old tool got that handful switch. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you have ruby(1.9.1+)

```
ruby -e 'puts Dir["chap*pdf"].sort_by{|x|x[/\d+/].to_i}'
```

Comment: One more nice thing about Ruby. Thanks for the info. Good luck in so.com. :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to rename the files so you don't have to keep sorting them later:

```
for f in chap*-solutions.pdf; do num=`echo $f | grep -o "[0123456789]\+"`; two_num=`printf "%02d" $num`; mv $f chap$two_num-solutions.pdf; done
```

- `grep -o "[0123456789]+"` outputs the chapter number (one or two digits)
- `printf` returns a string that contains the zero-padded number

Comment: And this is what they call "thoughtful". It touched my intention of renaming some files. Thanks a lot :D